# Low Bits in Assembler?

Tags: assembly

ND Arm9

The main problem is finding how to get the lower 32 and the higher 32 bits.
I would really appreciate any kind of help or hint so I can keep on doing this homework.

Comment: Which assembler language, for which machine?

Comment: what kind of assembler... please...

Comment: For a NDS We are programming the arm 9 if I'm not wrong.

Comment: You add a 32-bit number to a 32-bit number and the high 32 bits of the 64-bit result should be the final result? If this is true then the result can only be 0 or 1: If the 32-bit addition results in carry flag set then it is 1, otherwise it is 0. In this case a 32x32->32 bits multiplication is sufficient (the high bits get lost in using the "mul" instruction).

Comment: I multiply a 32 with a 32 and get a 64 then I grab the 32 lowbits and add to those 32bits then grab 32 higherbits and resulting a final seed of 32bits.

Comment: @Veni is the C code meant to end with `High32(seed32)`? Martin's right — if you add two 32-bit numbers you either get carry or you don't. If you get carry then the top 32 bits will be the decimal number '1'. If not then they'll be '0'.

Comment: @Tommy Did the question get edited?  High32(a) seems to be right to me a is the result of the multiplication step.

Comment: @stonemetal I think that wouldn't match the verbal description, though it would make more sense. Then seed32, which is presumably a global, mutates over time so that you get a stream of pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @stonemetal: Yes, the answer has been edited. In the old version I understood that the last line was "return High32(seed32);" and not "return High32(a);".

Comment: @Tommy Yes this code in theory has to create random numbers

Comment: @Martin Rosenau At the end I have to return the following:
A seed32 is given to me I have to multiply this for a 32bits then grab the lower 32 and add to those 32bits then to this result grab the higher 32 bits and return them.
Sorry if I'm not as clear as I should because my english is not good and it is even harder for me to explain this in my nativ language.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some ARM processors (not sure about ARM 9) have a 32x32 -> 64 bit multiplication instruction named "UMULL" (unsigned numbers) or "SMULL" (signed numbers).

The result is placed in two registers; one register will contain the low 32 and the other one will contain the high 32 bits so you do not even have to separate the low and the high bits!

If your processor does not have an "UMULL" instruction you'll have to do what "dwelch" writes in his answer.

Comment: Thank you now I will try do as you say and hope I can find a way of solving the problem. Really thanks, even if it does not work I really appreciate your effort to help!

Thanks.

Comment: I can use UMULL and SMULL.Searching I've found the information in "http://es.scribd.com/doc/40069778/54/UMULL-%E2%80%93-Unsigned-Multiply-Long" there I can see how to use UMULL for example:
Usage and Examples:UMULL performs an unsigned 32x32 multiply operation. The product of Rm and Rs isstored as a 64-bit unsigned value in the register pair Rd_MSW:Rd_LSW. All values areinterpreted as unsigned binary.The instruction below stores the product of R2 and R3 as a 64-bit number in R1:0.UMULL R0, R1, R2.
What I don't see is how to get from there the Lower or higher bits.
Thanks

Comment: One of the main problem is that they have not taught how to use assembler very deeple. Last year we had to do a little software that just multiplied and did little operations compared to this one, so with the same info that last year and less time and more dificulty... It is to hard at least for me.

Comment: I think as I read "http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasmref/armasmref_Cihbjehg.htm" that the UMULL uses Rlo,Rhi,Rn,Rm and for example if you had to Multiply A*B and get the higher you should do the following:
UMULL R1,R2,R3,R4-->Being r3=A; r4=B; and then consulting the r2 to know the higher 32 bits. Is this correct?

Comment: Another problem has appeared. How to make the same but with addition so I can grab the higher 32 bits?
I'm looking but have no luck finding an instruction that does that.

Answer (score 1):

In this case your question has little if anything to do with the programming language, so asm, C, Pascal, Python, it doesnt matter (unless you are only interested in shortcuts then it might for the high level languages).

So, back to elementary school math.  Multiplying two numbers:

```
  12
* 34
====
   8  (4*2)
  40  (4*10)
  60  (30*2)
+300  (30*10)
====
 408
```

But what if our computer had a limit on the number of digits (bits) it could operate on. If for example our hardware could multiply two 8 bit numbers, very quickly on a calculator, or in your head, 0xFF is the largest unsigned number that times itself 0xFF * 0xFF = 0xFE01, just to check in decimal in case there is a sign issue with the calculator 255 * 255 = 65025 = 0xFE01.  Here are two more in case you dont see the pattern, a two bit multiply, the biggest number is 3, 3*3 = 9, 0b11 * 0b11 = 0b1001.  Two bits in, needs four bits out to completely cover the possibilities, 8 bit operands require a 16 bit result to completely cover the possibilities.  Correct me if I am wrong but IF your processor has a multiply at all and the result is not twice the input in size, then what must you do?  Arguably you can only use that hardware in one of a few ways, try the multiply if there is an overflow flag then work around that issue (the entire purpose of this answer is how to work around the issue), otherwise you are ok with that result.  So if you have a 32 bit * 32 bit = 32 bit mulitiply then that is only reliable when used as a 16 bit * 16 bit = 32 bit by making sure your inputs have their upper bits zero, or if you think harder about this and realize that one number could have a few more significant bits than 16 so long as the other has a few less than 16.

So using the decimal numbers I started with but stating that we can only take one digit numbers on the input of our multiply operation, and get a two digit result, and we can only take two digit numbers in our add and get a two digit result how do we perform 12*34?

Simple we look at the stuff in the middle

8  (4*2)
  40  (4*10)
  60  (30*2)
+300  (30*10)

And/or we do a little bit of basic math

```
12*34 = 
((1*10)+(2*1))*((3*10)+(4*1)) =
((1*10)*(3*10)) + ((1*10)*(4*1)) + ((2*1)*(3*10)) + ((2*1)*(4*1)) = 
((1*3)*(10*10)) * ((1*4)*(10*1)) + ((2*3)*(1*10)) + ((2*4)*(1*1))
```

If you dont see the answer yet keep reading.

If each of the digits were variables abcd, so instead of 12*34 in decimal we will represent the digits as ab*cd

```
ab*cd = 
((a*c)*(10*10)) + ((a*d)*(10*1)) + ((b*c)*(1*10)) + ((b*d)*(1*1))
```

Not seeing it yet?  We can do the single digit a*c, a*d, b*c, b*d now using the rule of one digit in, two digits out.  Multiplying by 100 or 10 or 1 is just shifting.

```
((a*c)*(10*10))  = a*c * 100 = (a*c) << 2 
((a*d)*(10*1))   = a*d * 10  = (a*d) << 1 
((b*c)*(1*10))   = b*c * 10  = (b*c) << 1 
((b*d)*(1*1))    = b*d * 1   = (b*d) << 0
```

Now what if we declared this to be instead of single decimal digits, hex digits and our multiplier could do 4 bit in 8 bit out.  and our adder could do 8 bit in 8 bit out.

```
((a*c)*(0x10*0x10))  = a*c * 0x100 = (a*c) << 8 
((a*d)*(0x10*0x1))   = a*d * 0x10  = (a*d) << 4 
((b*c)*(0x1*0x10))   = b*c * 0x10  = (b*c) << 4 
((b*d)*(0x1*0x1))    = b*d * 0x1   = (b*d) << 0
```

So if I had two 8 bit numbers in this system and I needed to multiply them cleanly and the best the instruction set had to offer was a 4 or 8 bit input multiply operation that had an 8 bit out result, and the addition was 8 bits in and 8 bits out.  To multiply my two 8 bit numbers jk * mn where j,k,m,n represent individual hexadecimal (four bit) numbers then

(temp0,1,2,3... are 8 bit registers/variables)

temp0 = j*m
temp1 = j*n
temp2 = k*m
temp3 = k*n

temp4 = ((temp1<<4)&0xFF) + ((temp2<<4)&0xFF)
if carry bit is set then temp0 = temp0+1;
temp4 = temp4 + temp3
if carry bit is set then temp0 = temp0 + 1
temp0 = temp0 + (temp1>>4)
temp0 = temp9 + (temp2>>4)

The upper 8 bits of the answer is in temp0 the lower 8 bits in temp4.

And this scales for any number of bits, 32 bits in, 32 bits out.  if you want to multiply a 1024 bit * 1024 bit = 2048 bit number using an 8 bit machine, 4 bit * 4 bit = 8 bit multiply and an 8 bit + 8 bit = 8 bit adder.  Then you can easily do it.

To not have to do all that written math then just do this

```
      jk
    * mn
    ====
      nk  (n*k<<0)
     nj   (n*k<<1)
     mk   (m*k<<1)
   +mj    (m*k<<2)
    ====
```

Pad with zeros if it helps

```
    00nk  
    0nj0  
    0mk0   
   +mj00    
    ====
```

Then split them apart to the width of our adder

```
    00  nk  
    0n  j0  
    0m  k0   
   +mj +00    
    ==  ==
```

Simplify a little

```
 nk  
 j0  
+k0   
=== 
lower half of answer

 0n 
 0m
 mj
+carry_out from lower half
====
upper half of answer
```

A three digit number straight out of elementary school

```
    abc
  * def
========
     fc (fc = f times c)
    fb0 (fb = f times b)
   fa00
    ec0
   eb00
  ea000
   dc00   
  db000
+da0000
========
```

then split up the addition into columns your add operation can digest...this scales up forever any size numbers you want operated on by any size multiply and add your processor supports.  If you dont have a multiply operation then it still works exactly the same way but one side of your multiplier (that you dont have) is a bit width of 1.

USING BITS NOW:

```
    abcd
   *1011
=======
    abcd   (abcd * 0b0001)
   abcd0   (abcd * 0b0010)
  000000   (abcd * 0b0000)
+abcd000   (abcd * 0b1000) 
========
```

a,b,c,d are bits now, and 1011 is a four bit number, in binary each digit can only be a 1 or a 0 so 0 times anything is zero, 1 times anything is itself so multiplying one number against another when you dont have a multiply operation simply means for every non-zero bit in one operand you shift the other operand by that amount and add it to your accumulated result.  not fast but very easy to implement on just about any processor, and it likewise scales indefinitely.

now apply all of this to your 32 bit * 32 bit = 64 bit multiply where you need to preserve the upper and lower halves of the result on whatever processor you are using in whatever programming language you are using.

Comment: Wow, incredible response but I thinks it's to far for me to comprehend.
I've done just a month of assembler and now I'm overwhelmed with this task. Thanks, for your time and patience, I will re-read your response and try use it as much as possible.
Thanks.